# Does Schwarz Inequality guarantee that the expectation value for an operator exists and is finite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

For two given square-integrable wave functions $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, Schwarz Inequality states that
$$|\int_a^bdx\phi^*\psi|\le\sqrt{\int_a^bdx\phi^*\phi\int_a^bdx\psi^*\psi}.$$
This guarantees that the inner product between the functions exists and is finite.
What about the expectation value? Does the relation guarantee the same thing when I am working instead with the integral form of expectation value for some operator $A$?

I think it does, since we are just taking the inner product between a wave function and that wave function worked on by $A$. But is my thought correct?

Comment: What if the operator grows very fast with $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for an arbitrary observable. For an explicit counter example, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519426/116526).

It is, however, easy to see that this is true when the observable is a bounded operator, i.e. one in which for any $\vert\psi\rangle$ with $\Vert\psi\Vert<\infty$, we have $\Vert A\vert \psi\rangle\Vert <\infty$. This is simply because
\begin{align}
\vert \langle \psi\vert A \vert \psi\rangle\vert \leq \big\Vert\psi\big\Vert~ \big\Vert A\vert \psi\rangle \big\Vert,
\end{align}
and $\Vert \psi\Vert < \infty$, $\Vert A\vert \psi\rangle\Vert <\infty$, with the latter being guaranteed since $A$ is bounded.